# Connecting signalr client with bot framework

Tags: signalr, botframework, signalr.client

I have a signalR hub for the live agent now i am trying to connect my bot framework with the signalR hub. For that, I have done the setup of the for the signalR client.
Then I have given the hub connection in the conversationstate accessor. then i am able to make the connection with the signalr hub. but when i try to access the state accessor hub connection i get the error as:
Unable to find a constructor to use for type Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client.HubConnection. A class should either have a default constructor, one constructor with arguments or a constructor marked with the JsonConstructor attribute. Path 'LiveAgentModel.connection.ServerTimeout'.

this is the code for model: ''' public class LiveAgentModel
{
public bool isConnected { get; set; } = false;

```
    public string agentConnectionId { get; set; }

    public string name { get; set; }

    public HubConnection connection;
}'''
```

this is where i am trying to access and getting error.

```
 public async Task OnTurnAsync(ITurnContext turnContext, NextDelegate next, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
        {
            var conversationStateAccessors = _conversationState.CreateProperty<LiveAgentModel>(nameof(LiveAgentModel));
            var conversationData = await conversationStateAccessors.GetAsync(turnContext, () => new LiveAgentModel()).ConfigureAwait(false);
}
```

i am getting the error after setting the value to connection when i am tring to get the value as below

```
 private async Task Escalate(ITurnContext sendTurnContext, Activity handoffEvent)
        {

            var conversationStateAccessors = _conversationState.CreateProperty<LiveAgentModel>(nameof(LiveAgentModel));
            var conversationData = await conversationStateAccessors.GetAsync(sendTurnContext, () => new LiveAgentModel()).ConfigureAwait(false);

    

           conversationData.connection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
            .WithUrl("https://localhost:44348/ChatHub")
            .Build();
```

Please help me in solving this.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently it is not possible to deserialize a HubConnection object and re-create it once you store it in the conversationState, I don't know if it is the best way to do it but it will allow you to have your hubconnection object alive:

create a class that contains a dictionary in which your key will be the "conversationId" of your user and the value will be your HubConnection object

1.- Create a class:

```
public class MyDictionaryClass{
    //Initialize to prevent null exception
  public Dictionary<string, HubConnection> diccionaryConnections= new Dictionary<string, HubConnection>();
}
```

2.- Create a singleton service (The dictionary will be available to all users, and will keep lls data while the application is running) in Startup.cs:

```
 services.AddSingleton<MyDictionaryClass>();
```

3.- Use the service:

We have to make use of dependency injection... example inside a dialog [Dependency injection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-5.0):

```
   public myDialog{
            MyDictionaryClass _myDictionaryService;
            
                //Constructor
                public myDialog(MyDictionaryClass myDictionaryService){
                _myDictionaryService = myDictionaryService;
                }
    
        
            }
```

4.- Into myDialog class add method

```
 public MyMethod(WaterfallStepContext stepContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken){
    
                 //check that the dictionary has a valid connection

                         if (_myDictionaryService.diccionaryConnections.ContainsKey(stepContext.Context.Activity.Conversation.Id)) {
                    
              //Dictionary has user connection... Make something 

 var connection = _myDictionaryService.diccionaryConnections[dialogContext.Context.Activity.Conversation.Id]

 await **conexion**.InvokeAsync("HubMethod", "Hello someone");
                                            }
                                            else {
                                            //the dictionary has no user connection... create connection to signalr
                       
                             var conexion =  new HubConnectionBuilder()
                                    .WithUrl("https://localhost:[MYPORT]/ServerHub")
                                    .Build();
                //Add to dictionary
                                    _myDictionaryService.diccionaryConnections.Add(conversationId, conexion);
            //Send message to HubServerMethod
            await conexion.InvokeAsync("HubMethod", "hi my frend");
                                     
    
           }
                    }
```

*You should consider the possible user scenarios and signalR events (connected, reconneccted, disconnected, etc) [Events SignalR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/handling-connection-lifetime-events) so that you **add and remove elements from the dictionary**, possibly this solution will allow you to continue working and investigating

***It is important that you keep in mind that the singleton dictionary only lives while the application is running, and if you find how to improve it, I would like to know.**